# Dynamically searching for values that match condition in list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data that looks like this:
[image]

I want a python function that searches the date whose values are less than -1 or greater than 1 in a non-consecutive manner. In other words,

It should result in 
3/17/1993 (date whose value is less than -1),
3/24/1993 (date whose value is greater than +1)
3/25/1993 (date whose value is less than -1)
3/29/1993 (date whose value is greater than +1)
4/1/1993 (date whose value is greater than +1).

It should skip, for example, 3/18/1993 because even though its value (-1.3) is less than -1, we already encountered 3/17/1993 whose value is less than -1.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = dict( a= 0.2, b= 0.3, c= -1.5, d= -1.3, e= 0.3, f= 0.2, g= 12, h= -1.2, i= -1.3, j= 1.4, k= 0.3)
neg = True
for (k,v) in data.items():
  if((neg and v<-1) or (not neg and v>1)):
    print(k)
    neg = not neg
```

returns:

```
c
g
h
j
```

The logic is the same with a dict or a dataframe though make sure your keys are sorted:

```
(pi6 637) $ cat /tmp/x.py
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF8 -*-

import pandas as pd

data = dict( a= 0.2, b= 0.3, c= -1.5, d= -1.3, e= 0.3, f= 0.2, g= 12, h= -1.2, i= -1.3, j= 1.4, k= 0.3)
df = pd.Series(data)

neg = True
for i,r in df.sort_index().iteritems():
  if((neg and r<-1) or (not neg and r>1)):
    print(i)
    neg = not neg

(pi6 638) $ /tmp/x.py
c
g
h
j
```

Comment: I think it works well for dictionary, but can we do the same thing for dataframe object?